# ERROR 1200: Unexpected Symbol?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

I was programming in pig, and an error occurred, which I have not been able to resolve.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
--Load files into relations
month1 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201201hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
month2 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201202hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
month3 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201203hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
month4 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201204hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
month5 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201205hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
month6 = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/201206hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');

--Combine relations
months = UNION month1, month2, month3, month4, month5, month6;

/* Splitting relations
SPLIT months INTO 
        splitMonth1 IF SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) == '01',
        splitMonth2 IF SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) == '02',
        splitMonth3 IF SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) == '03',
        splitRest IF (SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) == '04' OR SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) == '04');
*/

/*  Joining relations

stations = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/QCLCD201211/stations.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (id:int, name:chararray)

JOIN months BY wban, stations by id;

*/

--filter out unwanted data
clearWeather = FILTER months BY SkyCondition == 'CLR';

--Transform and shape relation
shapedWeather = FOREACH clearWeather GENERATE date, SUBSTRING(date, 0, 4) as year, SUBSTRING(date, 4, 6) as month, SUBSTRING(date, 6, 8) as day, skyCondition, dryTemp;

--Group relation specifying number of reducers
groupedMonthDay = GROUP shapedWeather BY month, day PARALLEL 10;

--Aggregate relation
aggedResults = FOREACH groupedByMonthDay GENERATE group as MonthDay, AVG(shapedWeather.dryTemp), MIN(shapedWeather.dryTemp), MAX(shapedWeather.dryTemp), COUNT(shapedWeather.dryTemp) PARALLEL 10;

--Sort relation
sortedResults = SORT aggedResults BY $1 DESC;

--Store results in HDFS
STORE SortedResults INTO 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/pigresults' USING PigStorage(':');
```

Here is the return that I get when I run the code:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: <file /home/eduardo/Documentos/pig/weather.pig, line 35, column 52>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'PARALLEL'

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. <file /home/eduardo/Documentos/pig/weather.pig, line 35, column 52>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'PARALLEL'
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1691)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1411)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:344)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:369)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: Failed to parse: <file /home/eduardo/Documentos/pig/weather.pig, line 35, column 52>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'PARALLEL'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1678)
    ... 15 more
================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are grouping more than one column you have to put inside function bracket

```
groupedMonthDay = GROUP shapedWeather BY (month, day) PARALLEL 10;
```

The other point is you can avoid multiple load and union by using the below command, this will load all the files starting with the above combination.

```
allMonths = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/[0-9]*hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Incase you want to load only the above six files from a bunch of files, then you can load like this

```
allMonths = LOAD 'hdfs:/data/big/data/weather/20120[1-6]*hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```